# Use capacitor to store energy during regenerative braking

Tags: capacitor, brushless-dc-motor, regenerative

I have a BLDC motor and I want to store the regenerative power when it is braking.

For doing so, I was thinking to use a capacitor bank between the driver and the power supply (48V DC). The peak current is about 2A in positive and -1A when braking.

My question is: is it possible to use a polarized capacitor that charges when the current is negative and discharges when the load requires a positive current?

Edit:

The circuit is the following:

[image]

The idea is to disconnect the power supply when the current is negative and re-connect it when positive. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes it is. Assuming you define positive and negative current flows suitably for the capacitor. You appear to be asking "is it possibly to push current into a polarised capacitor and draw current out of a polarised capacitor?". Which the answer is yes. Unless I am miss-understanding your question.

Comment: Yes, that is what capacitors do. Why don't you show a schematic of what you are considering and ask if it seems suitable?

Comment: I'm not an expert on motor control, but I _imagine_ that using a capacitor will be more of a design challenge than pushing power back to a fixed-voltage supply (e.g., like electric trains do) or back to a battery (e.g., like electric cars do) because the change in the capacitor's voltage as you store and remove energy will be much greater than in the other two cases.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Pushing power back into a fixed-voltage supply is very often a bad idea, because it moves the regulation of that supply into a completely different operating region.  (Seen the results of active braking into a voltage rail whose regulator was only specified for current sourcing and not sinking -- they weren't pretty)

Comment: @BenVoigt, That may be true, but the first practical use of regenerative braking was in electric railways and tramways back in the early 1900s, and those trains operated from a fixed-voltage supply. I was _not_ recommending that the OP try driving power back through a typical regulated power supply. I only was pointing out that a capacitor-based regenerative braking system has an additional design consideration that is not a problem is most other regenerative braking applications.

Answer (score 1):

In a brushless motor, the motor's speed is proportional to the voltage, and the torque is proportional to the current.  When braking, the motor is acting as a generator but these principles remain.  So, it's not a simple as recifying the phase outputs and dumping them into a capacitor.

It will work at first:  An uncharged capacitor will short out the motor, hard-braking.  The capacitor will begin to charge, and the motor speed will drop, but the motor speed will eventually drop below the capacitor voltage.  The braking will cease, because no more current means no more braking torque.  So you will have a sudden "grab" followed by a loss of braking, and very high instantaneous currents.

Instead, regenerative braking circuits use pulse-width-modulated switching to control braking rates and to allow for braking to occur throughout the motor speed range.  In effect you will be using the phase outputs' power to run a switching power supply that can charge your battery or capacitor.  These types of circuits can recover 50% or more of the braking energy under the right conditions, but much is lost to heat.

So the answer to your question is yes;  this approach is used in battery-powered electric cars.  Batteries are preferred to capacitors because of their ability to store more energy, but a large capacitor bank is basically a battery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use electrolytic capacitors to store charge, but the problem is, how are you going to get that charge out of the motor while braking, and then source current from the capacitors to drive the motor while charging. It requires more circuitry than just the H-bridge, and you would have to somehow disconnect the power supply during braking to charge the capacitor, then connect it, and the capacitor (or capacitors) would only supply power for a very short time. To give you an idea of the energy stored, if you had a few 100 microfarad caps at 10 volts, you would be storing milliJoules of energy, which probably isn't enough to run the motor for very long.

$$ E=\frac{1}{2}CV^2$$

Comment: So a [3,000 Farad supercapacitor at 2.7V](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/eaton-electronics-division/XL60-2R7308W-R/5042378),  (having a 3Wh label) will hold 0.5*3000*2.7*2.7 will hold 10,935 joules? Might that be usable?

Comment: You'd need about 18 of those in series to get to 48v

Comment: We could probably use 8 in series, assuming voltage range from 2.7V down to 1.4V, and a boost converter from the resulting 21.6v - 11.2V , to reach that 48v...